# C: Passing a pointer down, updated pointer can't be accessed from calling functions!

Tags: c, pointers

I've got a problem- I assign my pointer variable to something in a called function, but when trying to access the updated pointer in the calling functions, it doesnt show as updated, and results in a seg fault. Help!

"Bottommost function":

```
void compareStrings(char* firstFrag, char* secondFrag, int* longestCommonLength, char* suffix, char* prefix, int* relative_pos) {
    suffix = firstFrag;
    prefix = secondFrag;
}
```

It is called from this function (the printf triggers the fault)

```
int findBestOverlap(char* fragmentArray[], int fragmentCount, int* longestCommonLength, char* suffix, char* prefix, int* relative_pos) {
    compareStrings(fragmentArray[firstFrag], fragmentArray[secondFrag], longestCommonLength, suffix, prefix, relative_pos);
    printf("LCL: %i || PREFIX: %s || SUFFIX: %s", *longestCommonLength, prefix, suffix);
}
```

The variables prefix and suffix are in turned created in a higher calling function, processStrings.

```
void processStrings(char* fragmentArray[], int fragmentCount) {
    int longestCommonLength = 0;
    char* suffix;
    char* prefix;
    int relative_pos;  // Where the first letter of suffix is, vis-a-vis prefix

    if ((findBestOverlap(fragmentArray, fragmentCount, &longestCommonLength, suffix, prefix, &relative_pos)) != 0) {
    }
}
```

Help!

Answer (score 3):

You're not updating the pointer, you're just changing the local value of the argument. You need to use a pointer pointer (e.g. `char**`) and change the pointed-to value instead.

```
void compareStrings(char* firstFrag, char* secondFrag, int* longestCommonLength, char** suffix, char** prefix, int* relative_pos) {
    *suffix = firstFrag;
    *prefix = secondFrag;
}
```

Then you need to dereference it appropriately in the caller. Have fun!

Comment: Do I need to do it successively down the calling functions? Like char*** and then **suffix?

Comment: Rarely. And the caller will probably use something like `&foo` to pass a `char*`.

Comment: and when I'm passing from the intermediate calling function, should I pass *suffix or just suffix?

Comment: Any function that needs to change the value has to use a pointer pointer. If the function just reads the value then a pointer is fine.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. Power to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need this functionality, you can either pass a pointer to the caller's copy of the pointer (so the called function can use that to write back to it) or you can simply return a pointer which the caller is expected to store and use.